# How can I find the last occurence of a character in a string and get everything before it?

Tags: php, replace, substring

For now, I am doing:

```
$lastpart = strrchr( $string, '-');
$firstpart = str_replace($lastpart, '', $string);
```

or

```
$array = explode('-',$string);
array_pop($array);
$firstpart = implode('-',$array);
```

But it seems like there must be a native function that does all this at once. Is there a function which can find the last occurence of a string and return everything before it?

**Just to clarify**, these solutions work fine, but I'm looking for a *native* function.

Comment: Can you show the string you want to find the last part?

Comment: @Zerquix18, I would like a native php function that will work on any string.

Comment: **Just to clarify** there is *no* native function for this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

```
$newString = substr($oldString, 0, strrpos($oldString, $character));
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question (for a native function), but it _is_ a better solution than the two that I've been using.

Comment: There is no native function for this, only a native function for the last character. This is very typical of PHP's string handlers, leaving you the flexibility to combine them for specific use.

Comment: I'll give you the check because you did it on one line, even though @Justin-iurman answered 20 seconds before you did with the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions :

Considering `a` to be the string you are looking for :

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.*)a([^a])*$/', '\\1', 'asdfabcd');
```

$string here will result in `asdf`

ref : [php.net/preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace)